# Deceleration in vscode

Tags: javascript, react-native

I faced the problem of deceleration of JavaScript code, see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please include the code and error message as text and not as an image.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see the mistake you made is in return statement you enclose it with curly bracket instead of a parentheses.

Change you code to look like this

```
export const Login = () => {
  return (
   <View></View>
  )
}
```